# How to reuse Android axml layout design inside another axml layout in xamarin

Tags: android-layout, xamarin.android

I have a axml layout design which i want to use in another next layout? How can i do that if it is possible.
My reusable sample axml code as follows

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
     <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="20"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <refractored.controls.CircleImageView 
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/door_image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:civ_border_width="0dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        android:src="@drawable/fingerprint_icon" />
     </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reuse" in another layout? Like elements in listview?

Comment: can i include this layout in other layouts without adding whole code. just wanted to refer this layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the layout that you want to re-use, create a new XML file and define the layout. For example, here's a layout that defines a title bar to be included in each activity (titlebar.xml):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/titlebar_bg"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" >

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/gafricalogo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The root View should be exactly how you'd like it to appear in each layout to which you add this layout.

**Use the include Tag**

Inside the layout to which you want to add the re-usable component, add the  tag. For example, here's a layout that includes the title bar from above:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

*Source: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include*